# WebSockets or periodical Ajax requests?

Tags: php, ajax, websocket

I have project for managing sport tournaments. It is written in PHP / Laravel. I need to publish match results on webpage asynchronously ("online"),  while the tournament is running. I cannot decide, which way of communication is more suitable for my situation. Periodic ajax requests (e.g. 1 request per 10 seconds) or WebSockets? Could you please advise me? Could you please also mention some pros & cons of both ways?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using these requests for mobile version also definitely go with `websockets` cause ajax(http) calls will affect on battery life of mobile and this example will demonstrate that http calls need more *energy* for work as compare to websockets.

if you don't need the specific benefits that WebSockets provides, then it's probably a better idea to stick with existing techniques like AJAX and Comet because this allows you to re-use and integrate with a huge existing ecosystem of tools, technologies, security mechanisms, knowledge bases (i.e. far more people on stackoverflow know HTTP/Ajax/Comet than WebSockets), etc.